# Stack Overflow Careers - Change Owner not working 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I tried to find a specific meta site for careers... but I'm guessing SO & Careers bugs all get channeled through here

We're trying to transfer ownership of my company's careers profile to myself, but clicking on the Change Owner link only delivers the following result.

Upon loading the Company Settings page we get a:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
     (anonymous function) @ VM769:2
     (anonymous function) @ VM769:708
```

And clicking on the link itself results in a `404`:

```
GET https://careers.stackoverflow.com/accounts/123456/assign-company-page/1046?_=9999888811110 404 (NotFound)
```

We've received this issue on multiple computers from different locations which I believes rules out connectivity issues on our side of the pond (being in South-Africa)

Comment: Is this still an issue? If so can you please email careers@stackoverflow.com with details of the profile you're trying to assign?

Comment: @AlexWarren, yes. This is currently still broken. My colleague actually shared his login details with me for his careers profile so I can update the Company Page... but as I've stated, the transfer link is a no go as of yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for taking so long to get back to you!

Only company administrators can change the ownership of a company page. You can find the list of administrators for your company on [the Team Account page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/company-profile/users).

Obviously we also need to fix the site so it gives correct instructions here.